Troubles with Speakers, touchpad, touch-pen on my Laptop HP
Hi, I'm having two problems with my new Ubuntu 24.04 install
problems with Touchpad, Speakers and Touch Pen
Given that I love free software so much and in particular I don't want to give up using Ubuntu, I would therefore like to ask for help from any user more experienced than me to solve these problems

My HP laptop has 4 built-in speakers,
for some reason the audio sounds at too low a volume, as if only 2 were used,
on Windows this didn't happen and the audio was voluminous

The touchpad is large in my pc, to press the left button,
the software forces me to press the farthest corner, and it's terribly inconvenient,
instead I would like it possible to press a little on the entire lower left side of the touchpad,To
and vice versa for the right, this also worked on windows

On windows I had a method to write text in any search field using my touch pen,
my PC has a touchscreen display with an integrated pen, when I pressed on the search field I just had to touch it with the pen and a window appeared where I could write by hand what I wanted to search for and the software, recognizing the written words, transcribed them into the search field , do you know a similar software/service for Ubuntu?



recognizing the written words, transcribed them into the search field , do you know a similar software/service for Ubuntu? -- No. For writing text, you can use online handwriting recognition tools, but not for searching in the menu. Use the on screen keyboard instead.

Please provide more details about the model number of the computer;

Hi Archisman, this is my new beautiful laptop ^_^ i love it
https://www.hp.com/it-it/shop/product.aspx?id=a1st9ea&opt=abz&sel=ntb

Considering that you usually use Windows, and now moved to Ubuntu, there's still a few things here that is still amiss.

If it's usually voluminous in Windows and not in Ubuntu, it's possible that you're using an audio enhancement software or any kind, and to increase the volume (exceeding 100%) in ubuntu, one solution is to over amplify it. Open settings, then click (or tap) on Sound, then enable Over-Amplification. Increase it to however you like, though I don't recommend this.
For the handwriting solution, it's not possible for now. But you could use any online handwriting recognition tools, and paste it in the search field. Or enable Screen Keyboard in the Accessibility menu in Settings.
It is possible to tweak touchpad settings using gnome-tweaks, but be careful with this tool. Okay, once you install gnome-tweaks (sudo apt install gnome-tweaks), open it and click (or tap) on Keyboard and Mouse, and select "Fingers" in the Mouse Click Emulation section.

All I recommend here is the best solution I could find, considering you just moved from Windows to Linux.

Thank you, point 3 touchpad solved finally with gnome tweaks! :D
1- Is not just voluminous in Windows.. My laptop has for real 4 speakers inside! I need to activate all speakers, just 2 are working and I don't know how do it, those are called "DTS:X® Ultra
Four speakers
HP Audio Boost
Poly Studio"

errrr, okay at least point 3 works.

It seems like you're using HP Spectre 14 inch x360 2-in-1 Laptop 14-EU0004TU, which include the dts studio speaker you mention. While DTS itself didn't release an official software, this could help (maybe) (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DTS%20Pulseaudio%20%28dcaenc%29)

thank you to answer me, I think is the right way, but for some reason it woldn't install pulse audio, at the end of those two commands:
chmod +x ./DTSPulseaudioInstaller
and
sudo ./DTSPulseaudioInstaller
Terminal say: Pulseaudio, no process if found
